# How to properly write my .htaccess to ignore a folder

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been searching arround for anwsers about what I am trying to do. I have an Angular.js application with the html5mode seted to true. So I created a .htaccess file to be able to run.

So far I have this.

```
# Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I have an admin panel palced in the folder /backend/ and when I try to get to it, I keep getting redirect to the /index.html.

I think it might have something to do with :

> '-d' (is directory) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests
>   whether or not it exists, and is a directory.

So far, I tried to add a new condition to the file, but I'm only getting 500 Internal errors so far.

```
# Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

**My goal** : Make the .htaccess ignore the RewriteRule if I stand in /backend/ folder pages.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/to/exclude`.

Comment: Can you give more information about where to place it with my actual structure of the .htaccess? When I place your code, it does work when I visit /backend/, but none on my frontpage are showing now. It said file not found.

EDIT : It is strange, because without this rule, if I manually write the URL, it works, but if I click on the admin link, I get redirected.

Comment: you should NOT be using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in the rules. you're dealing with URLs, and the parts of the path in the doc root are NEVER exposed to the outside world. rewrite works literally with just what's in the url, e.g. `example.com/foo/bar/baz.html` will have `foo/bar/baz.html` for the rewriting, and the fact that the file physically exists in `/home/sites/example.com/html/foo/bar/baz.html` is irrelevant.

Comment: When I remove the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, even without adding the new RewriteCond I am getting an instant Internal 500.

Comment: Only with one `%{REQUEST_URI}` (not 2): `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/`

Comment: My bad, did a typo error. As I told, if I use the 3 conditions, now all the files outside /backend/ are getting 404 not found and only pages in /backend/ are working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: With this part of code, the homepage getting 404 and backend redirect to homepage that returns to 404. All the other pages still worked if I go manually in the URL bar. Note :

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ?

Comment: Yes and it did not worked... The fun fact is that when I enter the complet link manually with my initial htaccess everything is just fine. I think it might be a "Angular.js html5mode" issue that is causing the redirection.

Comment: I have my Angular application running on the ROOT and I based my code ont this example [Angular.js html5mode](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/#thecode) to set my .htaccess. But I want to ignore the current rules if the user visit /backend/ where I use other kind of stuff.